# Get total sum for each month in DAX

Tags: sql-server, dax, ssas-tabular

I have a tabular mode analysis server connected to a sql server database. I want to get the total x per month, and I have the total x per day. So for example, I have a table DailyEvent with the first 2 columns like this, and I want the column "MonthXCount":

```
TimeID   XCount MonthXCount
20160429  3          11
20160430  8          11
20160501  4           4
```

So the total XCount for April is 11, so for every day in April I want 11. The total X count for may is 4 (so far).

What I have now is a MonthToDate total I think, calculated as:

```
=TOTALMTD(SUM('DailyEvent'[XCount]),'DailyEvent'[TimeID])
```

But I want to then have a column that puts the last value of the month in for every day of the month.

The end goal is to have a XCount by month graph in PowerBI, so I might not need to add the column here... I might be able to just tell PowerBi to graph the last day of the month, but I'm not sure how to do that and thought this would be easier.

Comment: is the definitely an mdx question? or should it be dax?

Comment: This is definitely a DAX question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader reader;

cmd.CommandText = "begin transaction t    
    update table dailyevent
    set monthxcount = (select top(1) monthxcount 
                            from dailyevent 
                            where MONTH(timeID) = 4 
                            order by monthxcount desc)
    where MONTH(timeID) = 4

    --commit only if the rows affected corresponds to the number of rows found for the month of april.

    commit";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

sqlConnection1.Open();

reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
// Data is accessible through the DataReader object here.

sqlConnection1.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks very much, but I'm not sure where to put this? I'm using visual studio and looking at the Model.bim file. I just typed in the equation above as a new column in the fx box. I am new to this and don't know how to apply what you suggested.

Comment: What language is it that you're using in VStudio?
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader reader;

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Customers";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

sqlConnection1.Open();

reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
// Data is accessible through the DataReader object here.

sqlConnection1.Close();

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a Calendar Table in your model connected to your data table?

If yes, let's say the Calendar Table is called *DimDate* and that it contains a column called *YearMonth*, then the formula would be:

```
Month Sales := SUMX(
                    VALUES(DimDate[YearMonth]),
                    SUM(DailyEvent[XCount])
                    )
```

If you don't have a Calendar Table, then you can create a calculated column in your table called YearMonth with this formula:

```
=LEFT(DailyEvent[TimeID], 6)
```

Then calculate the sum of Month Sales with:

```
Month Sales := SUMX(
                    VALUES(DailyEvent[YearMonth]),
                    SUM(DailyEvent[XCount])
                    )
```

Hope this helps!

A note with respect to the formula you were using:
Time intelligence functions, such as TOTALMTD, require Calendar Tables. Therefore, be sure to add one to your data model before using them.

Edit:

Another solution could be to create a date column:

```
     = DATE(
            LEFT(DailyEvent[TimeID], 4), 
            MID(DailyEvent[TimeID], 5, 2), 
            1)
```

Then drop that column in the X-axis of the graph and the XCount column in the Y-axis.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a measure calculation in Power BI, or in SSAS model, if there is a calendar table, make sure it is marked as date table otherwise the time logic will not work. I used the following query (DAX) it calculates the Month To Date

```
MtD :=CALCULATE(SUM('DailyEvent'[XCount]),DATESMTD('DateTabe'[calendarDate]))
```

If however there is no calendar or you are working with the be-spoke calendar, this may help
[Running Totals Whitout a Traditional Calendar Table](https://p3adaptive.com/2011/06/running-totals-without-a-traditional-calendar-table/)